# Convert timestamp from excel to a matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, csv, datetime, timestamp

I have a csv file with timestamp column. One example timestamp:`43606.4791492245`.
If I insert this number in Excel, it gives me a correct time:`5/21/2019  11:29:58 AM`.
But I need to convert it to a Matlab datetime object.
I tried:

```
d = datetime(43606.4791492245, 'ConvertFrom', 'posixtime')
d = 
  datetime
   01-Jan-1970 12:06:46
```

And it is incorrect result.

**Could you help me to convert this timestamp correctly? What kind of magic happens inside Excel conversion?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, use the 'excel' format:

```
datetime(43606.4791492245, 'ConvertFrom', 'excel')
```

which returns 21-May-2019 11:29:58.

Apparently, 'excel' datenums are the number of days between the given date and 31-Dec-1899, as you can read on the [MATLAB documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#d123e286233).

Quoting MrFuppes' comment below for a better explanation:

*In Excel serial date, day 0 is [...] 1899-12-31. But since Excel inherited the leap year "bug" from Lotus 123 (1900 incorrectly considered a leap year), it is common to use 1899-12-30 as day zero. Between ordinal dates 0 and 60, this actually gives wrong results too, but most of the time, you won't encounter dates in that range.*

Comment: there is no `0-Jan-1900` ;-) In Excel serial date, day 0 is therefore `1899-12-31`. But since Excel inherited the leap year "bug" from Lotus 123 (1900 incorrectly considered a leap year), it is common to use `1899-12-30` as day zero. Between ordinal dates 0 and 60, this actually gives wrong results too, but most of the time, you won't encounter dates in that range. Matlab's `datetime` has that fixed though I think.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for the interesting clarification! I'll add it to the answer or feel free to also suggest an edit.

Comment: there's also a [nice story by Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/) around this Excel date thing - not so many technical details but an entertaining read :)